# Values update in GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a simple code for a GUI using tkinter. My problem is that I want to have a number, printed in the Label named t1, always updated as the sum of the two entries given. Of course I cannot use the .get method on the entries, since I would fix the values when calling the method, but I don't know hot to build a new (always updated) IntVar using other Intvar.

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

p1_in=StringVar()
p1=Entry(window,textvariable=p1_in)

p2_in=StringVar()
p2=Entry(window,textvariable=p2_in)

t1=Label(window,textvariable=(p1_in+p2_in))    # of course this doesn't work
t1.grid(row=7,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

How can I make the label t1 being always updated with the sum of p1_in+p2_in?
I know that they are StringVar, but the output is nicer for my intents this way, plus I don't think this is the main issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trace method of [StringVar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). It is called right after the value changes.

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

def calculate(*args):
    if p1_in.get() and p2_in.get(): #checks if both are not empty
        try:
            ans = int(p1_in.get()) + int(p2_in.get())
            t1_out.set(str(ans))
        except ValueError:
            t1_out.set("Enter integers!")

p1_in=StringVar()
p1=Entry(window,textvariable=p1_in)
p1_in.trace("w", calculate)

p2_in=StringVar()
p2=Entry(window,textvariable=p2_in)
p2_in.trace("w", calculate)

t1_out=StringVar()

t1=Label(window,textvariable=t1_out) #also note that used another variable for output
t1.grid(row=7,column=2)
p1.grid(row=5,column=2)
p2.grid(row=6,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```